# How to use Typescript Async/ await with promise in Node JS FS Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, fs

How to use Typescript async / await function and return typescript default promises in node js FS module and call other function upon promise resolved.

Following is the code :

```
  if (value) {
     tempValue = value;
     fs.writeFile(FILE_TOKEN, value, WriteTokenFileResult);
            }

 function WriteTokenFileResult(err: any, data: any) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }
        TOKEN = tempValue;
        ReadGist(); // other FS read File call
    };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For now I think there is no other way as to go with wrapper function. Something like this:

```
function WriteFile(fileName, data): Promise<void>
{
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        fs.writeFile(fileName, data, (err) => 
        {
            if (err)
            {
                reject(err);    
            }
            else
            {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });        
}

async function Sample()
{
    await WriteFile("someFile.txt", "someData");
    console.log("WriteFile is finished");
}
```

There is some lengthy discussion here about promises in node.js: [Every async function returns Promise](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11)

Answer (score 46):

Since NodeJS 10.0.0 [fsPromises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options) module can be used to achieve this result.

```
import { promises as fsPromises } from 'fs';
await fsPromises.writeFile('file.txt', 'data')
```

Comment: This is so awesome, I can't believe (a) that I didn't know this and (b) that this isn't the top answer.

Comment: @GreeneCreations It's all about timing. My answer came more then two years after Amid answer. The fsPromises was not a reality at that time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write the Promise wrappers yourself you can use [async-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-file).

Using this your code could look something like the following...

```
(async function () {
  //...
  await fs.writeFile(FILE_TOKEN, value);
  var data = await fs.readFile('gist');
  // do something with your "gist" data here...
})();
```